# database connection manngement in application

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I am developing a application that is in **php and PostgreSQL**.

What I want to know is which of these is best?

1. I should create connection every time i have to make a query like
       using pg_connect and close it after the query operations
2. Or should i start the connection first time at the initial launch

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0):

Connect at the start of your script, close it at ending. No need to re-connect on each query.